# Are magnetic forces medium-dependent?

Tags: electromagnetism

I am learning the **Magnetic Effects of Electric Currents** at school, and I was given an equation. I was told it would be elaborated on next year. But since I can't seem to bring myself to wait, here it is:

> B = µ<sub>o</sub>I/2πr

Now, **µ<sub>o</sub>** is supposed to be the **permeability of vacuum**. 
This suggests that there exist other values of permeability, which would effect the overall Magnetic force. Now, I still have a lot to learn, so please forgive any silliness that may arise in my question,

But is Magnetism, then, medium-dependent? Does the power of a magnet change when in a vacuum so as to then when in air or water or any other **matter**, for that matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two quantities associated with magnetic field. One is called magnetic field strength (denoted H) and the other is called magnetic flux density (denoted B). See [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_flux_density) The main difference between them is that H is medium independent and B is material dependent.

With respect to the medium effect, B is affected by the medium, they are related by:

[image]

In the previous equation I already described B and H. µ<sub>o</sub> is the free space permeability which is always constant, µ<sub>r</sub> is the relative permeability which is material dependent. Any material that has non-unity relative material is called a magnetic material.

In general, magnetic forces depend on B which is material dependent. So for the same current in a wire in vacuum and a wire in a medium that has relative permeablity not equal to 1, then the magnetic force will be different. In mathematics, they will have the same H but different B.

Comment: Your seems very helpful, but I am having difficulty understanding it. I shall give it more time, as physics always seems to bestow understanding upon me with time. :D

Comment: Maybe you should. But I will make a last try to make it simple!! Briefly, the magnetic strength of a current or a permanent magnet is the same regardless of material. But the effect it has (the force it exerts) depends on material. It is somehow like Newton second law, you apply the same force to bodies with different masses and you get different accelerations. In this case you apply the same field strength in two different materials and you get two different forces. Did that help?

Comment: Well, that definitely helps me understand your answer. But I still need to clarify one thing. Magnetism is not medium dependent, then? At all?

Comment: Magnetic field strength is not. So the strength of the magnet (whether it is current or bar magnet) is not medium dependent. But the force they exert on say a particle depends on medium. Think of sun rays during med-day, if you wear green glasses you see everything in green, if the glasses are red you see everything in red. The sun rays are the same but the way you see them is different. In that example, the sun rays are magnetic field strength, the glasses are the medium and you are the particle that feels the magnetic force.

Comment: Well, isn't that something to bring up in Physics class!
Thanks. Really appreciate it.